# Error with output string contain the special charachter using VBScript

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I have the code as below:

```
Dim title
title ="Parlez-en à votre Responsable formation";
Response.Write(title)
```

In fact, it shows me `Parlez-en  Ã  votre Responsable formation` is not the string I want.
And I also use this string to send mail in Ms.outlook it displays the string like this too.Anyone help me please, thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, you need to explain more. What do you mean you want to show it in Outlook? And why is it the string wrong, I assume you mean the fault is with the Ã?

Comment: I want to display string like this `Parlez-en à votre Responsable formation`

Comment: where you want to display it??

Comment: So, what has this got to do with Outlook? Is the error in Outlook or on a browser?

Comment: I put it as subject of mail in outlook, so it's error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a ASP question, i'll change the tags.
You need to set the response charset.
Happy coding !

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<%Response.charset="utf-8"%>
<%
    Dim title
    title ="Parlez-en à votre Responsable formation"
    Response.Write(title)
  %>
</body>
</html>
```